# elasticSearch to index from other table

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am new to elastic search and I am trying to index my product data into the elastic search.

I am using the below SQL query to get the products to indexed.

```
Select ProductID, ProductName, ShortDescription from product.
```

Now I have product ratings in other tables. It contains a list of ratings for each product, I need to get the average of the rating and add it to the index. So that whenever I receive the document, It will also contain the avg rating.

Can you guide us on how I need to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is getting the average rating, the short answer is "aggregation". Something like the following:

```
Select ProductID, ProductName, ShortDescription, Average(product_ratings.Rating)
From product
Join product_ratings
On product.ProductID = product_ratings.ProductID
Group By ProductID
```